# Node/Express/Javascript equivalent of Creating Instances of a join table, Iteratively

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, postgresql, express

What's the Node/Express/Javascript equivalent of creating instances of a join table, iteratively, like what I have below?

This is how I did it in Rails. "Interest" is the join table for "Politician" and "Category":

```
#This was in my seed.rb file

Politician.all.each do |politician|
  Category.all.each do |category|
    Interest.create(politician_id: politician.id, category_id: category.id)
  end
end
```

I ran rake db:seed and seed'ed this into my Postgres database.

This was my first crack at it in my Node/Express file, where I'm re-creating the exact same project. (btw, My models and associations are already defined earlier in the file):

```
Politician.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
    politiciansArray.forEach(function(politicianObject, index){
        Politician.create(politicianObject).then(function(politician) {

        Category.sync({force: true}).then(function(){
            categoriesArray.forEach(function(categoryObject, index){
                Category.create(categoryObject).then(function(category) {

                    politician.addCategory(category); 
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

});

This doesn't quite work because for every instance of Politician I create, category is created, which gives me double the amount of categories, and the interest table gets messed up too with bad data. I want to create/seed into my Postgres database an instance of Interest that combines a politician with a category, like how I did it in my Rails app. Does Node/Express have a "Politician.all" method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you simply trying to build a tree of objects in memory? And what database framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Express framework. I'm trying to seed a bunch of instances into my database. I'll need that for how I plan to set up my MVC. For every instance of politician and category, I need an instance of Interest that combine the two. It works that way in the Rails app I build. I'm just rebuilding it in Node/Express to learn Node.

Comment: I asked about the database framework, not about HTTP library.

Comment: I'm using a Postgres database